# looping through Struct Array gives me error request non-class type char

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I am just learning c++ and I am trying to use a struct to create a text adventure for myself and when I loop through the room object array, it gives me an error:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct location;

struct location {
    int roomid;
    string room_name;
    string room_desc;
};

int cur_room = 0;
location room[2];

int preloadroom();
int startgame();
int findroom(string room);

int main()
{

    preloadroom();
    startgame();
}

int preloadroom()
{
    room[0].roomid = 0;
    room[0].room_name = "The Cavern";
    room[0].room_desc = "A cavern in the woods where Shia Lebouf roams.";

    room[1].roomid = 0;
    room[1].room_name = "Cavern Bathroom";
    room[1].room_desc = "You are in the bathroom of the cavern.";
}

int findroom(string room)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        if (room[i].room_name == room) {
            cout << room[i].room_name;
            return 0;
        }

        cout << room[i].room_name;

        return 0;
    }

    int startgame()
    {

        string x;
        cout << ".. ........... .............  ........... . ..... ........ .......\n";
        cout << "......  ....................%.... .... ..... .........%............\n";
        cout << ".@@@ ........ @@.... @@@@  . ............................  *  .....\n";
        cout << "....@@ ..... @ .... @ .............   ....... .....; .... *** .....\n";
        cout << ".....\@\....@ .... @ ............................. #  .. *****  ...\n";
        cout << "@@@.. @@@@@  @@@@@@___.. ....... ...%..... ...  {###}  *******\n";
        cout << "....@-@..@ ..@......@@@\...... %...... ....... <## ####>********\n";
        cout << "@@@@\...@ @ ........\@@@@ ..... ...... ....... {###}***********\n";
        cout << "....%..@  @@ /@@@@@ . ....... ...............<###########> *******\n";
        cout << "...... .@-@@@@ ...V......     .... %.......... {#######}******* ***\n";
        cout << "...... .  @@ .. ..v.. .. . { } ............<###############>*******\n";
        cout << "......... @@ .... ........ {^^,     .......   {## ######}***** ****\n";
        cout << "..%..... @@ .. .%.... . .. (   `-;   ... <###################> ****\n";
        cout << ". .... . @@ . .... .. _  .. `;;~~ ......... {#############}********\n";
        cout << ".... ... @@ ... ..   /(______); .. ....<################  #####>***\n";
        cout << ". .... ..@@@ ...... (         (  .........{##################}*****\n";
        cout << "......... @@@  ....  |:------( )  .. <##########################>**\n";
        cout << "@@@@ ....@@@  ... _// ...... \\ ...... {###   ##############}*****\n";
        cout << "@@@@@@@  @@@@@ .. / /@@@@@@@@@ vv  <##############################>\n";
        cout << "@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ..... @@@@@@  @@@@@@@  @@@@\n";
        cout << "@@@@@@###@@@@@### @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n";
        cout << "@@@@@@@@###@##@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n";
        cout << "@@@@@@@@@@@### @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n";
        cout << "-@@@@@@@@@#####@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n";

        cout << "Your walking in the forest";
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "You are all alone";
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "You see a cavern in the distance and slowly make your way to it.";
        cin.ignore();
        system("clear");

        cout << room[cur_room].room_desc;
        cout << "Which room do you want to go to?";
        cin >> x;
        cout << x;
        findroom(x);
    }
```

It gives me this error on https://www.onlinegdb.com/:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int findroom(std::string)’: main.cpp:55:29: error: request for member ‘room_name’ in ‘room.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[], std::allocator >(((std::basic_string::size_type)i))’, which is of non-class type ‘char’
                 if (room[i].room_name == room){
                             ^~~~~~~~~ main.cpp:56:27: error: request for member ‘room_name’ in ‘room.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits,
_Alloc>::operator[], std::allocator >(((std::basic_string::size_type)i))’, which is of non-class type ‘char’
             cout<<room[i].room_name;
                           ^~~~~~~~~ main.cpp:61:17: error: request for member ‘room_name’ in ‘room.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits,
_Alloc>::operator[], std::allocator >(((std::basic_string::size_type)i))’, which is of non-class type ‘char’    cout<<room[i].room_name;
                 ^~~~~~~~~ main.cpp:66:16: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token  int startgame(){
                ^ main.cpp:112:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input  }
```

So, obviously I am doing something very wrong :-(

---

Edit: This is the full corrected code if it helps anyone:

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
struct location;

struct location {
    int roomid;
    string room_name;
    string room_desc;
    
    };
    
    int cur_room = 0;
    location room[2];
    
    int preloadroom();
    int startgame();
    int findroom(string room);
    
     
    
    int main() { 
    
    preloadroom();
    startgame();
    
}  
      
      
      
      int preloadroom(){
         room[0].roomid = 0;
          room[0].room_name = "The Cavern";
          room[0].room_desc = "A cavern in the woods where Shia Lebouf roams.";
          
          room[1].roomid = 0;
          room[1].room_name = "Cavern Bathroom";
          room[1].room_desc = "You are in the bathroom of the cavern.";
          
          
      }
      
      int startgame(){
 
     string x;
     cout<<".. ........... .............  ........... . ..... ........ .......\n";
 cout<<"......  ....................%.... .... ..... .........%............\n";
 cout<<".@@@ ........ @@.... @@@@  . ............................  *  .....\n";
 cout<<"....@@ ..... @ .... @ .............   ....... .....; .... *** .....\n";
 cout<<".....\@\....@ .... @ ............................. #  .. *****  ...\n";
  cout<<"@@@.. @@@@@  @@@@@@___.. ....... ...%..... ...  {###}  *******\n";
 cout<<"....@-@..@ ..@......@@@\...... %...... ....... <## ####>********\n";
   cout<<"@@@@\...@ @ ........\@@@@ ..... ...... ....... {###}***********\n";
 cout<<"....%..@  @@ /@@@@@ . ....... ...............<###########> *******\n";
 cout<<"...... .@-@@@@ ...V......     .... %.......... {#######}******* ***\n";
 cout<<"...... .  @@ .. ..v.. .. . { } ............<###############>*******\n";
 cout<<"......... @@ .... ........ {^^,     .......   {## ######}***** ****\n";
 cout<<"..%..... @@ .. .%.... . .. (   `-;   ... <###################> ****\n";
 cout<<". .... . @@ . .... .. _  .. `;;~~ ......... {#############}********\n";
 cout<<".... ... @@ ... ..   /(______); .. ....<################  #####>***\n";
 cout<<". .... ..@@@ ...... (         (  .........{##################}*****\n";
 cout<<"......... @@@  ....  |:------( )  .. <##########################>**\n";
  cout<<"@@@@ ....@@@  ... _// ...... \\ ...... {###   ##############}*****\n";
 cout<<"@@@@@@@  @@@@@ .. / /@@@@@@@@@ vv  <##############################>\n";
 cout<<"@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ..... @@@@@@  @@@@@@@  @@@@\n";
 cout<<"@@@@@@###@@@@@### @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n";
 cout<<"@@@@@@@@###@##@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n";
 cout<<"@@@@@@@@@@@### @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n";
 cout<<"-@@@@@@@@@#####@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n";
    
    
    
    
    
    
    cout<<"Your walking in the forest";
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"You are all alone";
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"You see a cavern in the distance and slowly make your way to it.";
    cin.ignore();
    system("clear");
    
    cout<<room[cur_room].room_desc;
    cout<<"Which room do you want to go to?";
   cin>>x;
    cout<<x;
    findroom(x);
}


      
      int findroom(string roomName) {
          int i;
           for ( i = 0; i < 1; i++){
                if (room[i].room_name == roomName){
            cout<<room[i].room_name;
            return 0;
                
                }
           }
          
  cout<<room[i].room_name;
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in your findroom function you take a parameter of type string called room, which means `room[i]` would be a char, which means `room[i].room_name` can't work because a char doesn't have a property called room_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have `location room[2];` as a global variable. Then you have the function `int findroom(string room)` inside of which you have the line `if (room[i].room_name == room)`

The problem is that function parameter is hiding the global because it has the same name. So the compiler is treating the first `room` there as a string and getting confused.

The solution is to rename one of those `room`s to make them distinct. This is one of the many reasons to be careful with global variables - name them in ways that you aren't going to accidentally reuse elsewhere in the program.

Answer (score 0):

you have conflicting names on the room array, declared globally, and the room string, declared as parameter at `findroom` function. What happens is that you are trying to access the string in search of a member of the location struct, hence the failure. Change the `findroom` function to something like this:

```
int findroom(string roomName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        if (room[i].room_name == roomName) {
            cout << room[i].room_name;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```